# Mongoose updating sub document array's individual element(document)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Schema of group and member are as below:

```
var group=new Schema({ 
    group_id:Number,
    group_name:String,
    members:[member]
});

var member=new Schema({
    member_id:number,
    name:String,
});
```

Sample document after inserting some record in group collection

```
[{
  _id:55ff7fca8d3f6607114dc57d
  group_id:1001,
  group_name:"tango mike",
  members:[
    {
      _id:44ff7fca8d3f6607114dc21c
      member_id:2001,
      member_name:"Bob martin" ,
      address:String,
      sex:String 
    },

    {
      _id:22ff7fca8d3f6607114dc22d
      member_id:2002,
      member_name:"Marry",  
      address:String,
      sex:String
    },

    {
      _id:44ff7fca8d3f6607114dc23e
      member_id:2003,
      member_name:"Alice" ,
      address:String,
      sex:String 
    }
  ]

}]
```

**My problem:**

I am trying to update record of individual group member(element of subdocument members). While updating I have follwing data group: `_id`, `group_id`, members:`_id`  and `newdata`. I am trying like this; but it is not working

```
var newData={
      member_name:"Alice goda" ,
      address:"xyz",
      sex:"F"
    }

groupModel.findOne({"_id":"55fdbaa7457aa1b9bd7f7cf7","group_id":1001},'members -_id',function(err,groupMembers){
          if(err)
          {
              res.json({
                  "isError":true,
                  "error":{
                      "status":1042,
                      "message":err
                  }
              });
          }
          else
          {
               var mem=groupMembers.id("44ff7fca8d3f6607114dc23e");
               mem.member_name=newData.member_name;
               mem.address=newData.address;
               mem.sex=newData.sex;

               mem.save(function(err,data){
                  if(!err)
                    //sucessfull updated
               });
               res.json(groupDetails);
          }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question details, you would like to update **one** object from the `members` array, in accordance with the criteria that you specify.

Thus, in order to accurately run the update query for your use case, you could run the following update operation against your collection:

```
db.collection.update({ _id: "55ff7fca8d3f6607114dc57d", 
                        group_id:1001, 
                        members: { 
                            $elemMatch: { _id: "44ff7fca8d3f6607114dc23e" }
                        } 
                      }, 

                      { $set: { 

                        "members.$.member_name": "Alice goda",
                        "members.$.address": "xyz",
                        "members.$.sex": "F"

                       }});
```

Still, be aware that the `$` positional operator only updates the first array item that matches your query.

Unfortunately, there is no possibility of updating all the array elements that match your criteria in a single operation. As you can see on [MongoDB Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243), the aforementioned feature is one of the most requested functionality, but it has not yet been directly implemented in MongoDB.